# Looking for a external drive that can be connected both with Gigabit ethernet and with eSATA

Tags: nas, storage, esata

I need to transfer the contents of a folder that currently exists on a SAN. There are about 650,000 files that take up 800 Gigabytes.

For the retrieval, I want to attach it to the server using gigabit ethernet and attach it as a SAN.

When I get the data to the final location, I would like to attach it as an eSATA drive.

I have found drives that work as a NAS and have eSATA available to add additional drives. But I need the ability to attach them as directly with eSATA to pull the files off the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After extensive research, such a device was not found.

Answer (score 0):

You can't usually attach a network hard drive as a SAN, unless it supports iSCSI.  Very few do.  You could just plug in with eSATA or USB2.0 directly to your server (most servers have USB2, but not many have eSATA) and let it copy the 800GB overnight (or over a weekend) then reverse the process.  External Hard drives that support eSATA and USB2 are very plentiful.

the more difficult part would be to ensure that the data was accurately copied over, and then accurately copied to the other system.  I would suggest a program to calculate the MD5 sums.  This is going to take a while.